# Is there any way I can share Videos on Chatter other Than youtube

Tags: chatter

Is there any way I can share Videos on Chatter other than posting it on YouTube.

I do not want to share content on YouTube, wanted to keep that within the organization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share screencast for user training or something and then keep it within organization, then I think you should following following steps -

Install http://www.techsmith.com/jing.html Jing free version and record screencast which is will be stored as a flash object and post if to chatter. When user clicks on it it will open as a Video. thats it.

Comment: Prafulla - The actual question just asked about how to share a video on chatter without linking to Youtube and didn't have anything to do with screencasts.  Could you please elaborate on how your answer is different than just uploading a video file from your hard drive to Chatter (created with whatever technology)?  Otherwise this answer seems kind of off topic to me and more like an answer to a question on "how do I create screencasts" which wouldn't belong on the Salesforce StackExchange.  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is a way.  Your users can attach files to Chatter posts themselves.  Here is the Salesforce help documentation.

> You can attach all file types, including Microsoft®
>   PowerPoint presentations and Excel spreadsheets, to Adobe® PDFs, image
>   files, audio files, and **video files**. The maximum file size is 2 GB.
>
> When you attach a file, consider the following:
>
> When a file is posted
>   to a feed, everyone in your company can see it even if the file
>   started out as private. Only files posted in a private group stay
>   private within that group.
>
> Attaching a file from a group or library
>   creates a reference to the file. If you update a file in Salesforce
>   CRM Content, the updates are also reflected in the feed.
>
> **Steps**
>
> 1. Click File at
>      the top of your feed to attach a file to a post, or Attach File below
>      a comment to attach a file to a comment.  If you’re commenting on an
>      update resulting from feed tracking on a file, the Attach File option
>      isn’t available.
> 2. Do one of the following: Click Select a file from
>      Salesforce to attach a file that someone has already uploaded. Click
>      Upload a file from your computer to attach new files from your
>      computer.
> 3. Browse for the file you want to attach. Links, Google docs,
>      documents from the Documents tab, and attachments from the Notes and
>      Attachments related list aren't included in the Select a File to
>      Attach list. For more information about finding files to attach, see
>      Searching for Files to Attach to a Chatter Feed.
> 4. Add a post or comment
>      about the file. If you don’t enter any text, a generic update is
>      posted with your attachment.
> 5. Click Share.

Answer (score 1):

In the Winter 13 release, Vimeo can be embedded in the feed as well, just like Youtube:

https://na1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_winter13_release_notes.pdf

see "Preview Links" on page 26

Answer (score 0):

Vimeo might be better for a couple of reasons - (1) Some companies block YouTube entirely (2) Vimeo's privacy conventions are slightly more usable than YouTube as they offer the ability to password protect individual videos.